# Как задать пагинацию в виде: "&paged=2" на вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Не могу разобраться и понять, как можно сделать пагинацию в виде: "&paged=2", на данный момент у меня стоит пагинация вида: "page/2/". Можно ли её как то поменять?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
function wp_disable_canonical_redirect( $query ) {
          remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wp_disable_canonical_redirect' );
```

Comment: А куда это нужно вставить?))

Comment: functions.php темы

Comment: Вставил как вы и сказали в functions.php темы, но не работает почему то...(((